# Como ocultar palavras curtas com PHP

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta que busca palavras-chave num texto e compara com as cadastradas pelo cliente. Se houver coincidência, ele então dispara um e-mail ao cliente.

A questão é a seguinte: quero dispensar da consulta as palavras curtas, como "de", "com", etc.

Exemplo: "Locação de veículos Tipo Ônibus", o resultado pretendido será: "Locação, veículos, tipo, Ônibus".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma vez que diz

> como "de", "com", etc

Aparentemente deseja remover as preposições, não apenas "palavras curtas", então poderia criar uma array com as preposições mais comuns (...):

```
$lista = ["a", "o", "as", "os", "com", "em", "por", "per", "ante", "contra", "entre", "sem", "após", "de", "para", "sob", "até", "desde", "perante", "sobre"];
```

Se houverem muitos textos, poderia considerar verificar quais são os mais frequentes, já que estas palavras frequentes dentem a ser justamente os "de", "para", "em"...

---

Então, poderia simplesmente usar um loop e remove-los :

```
$texto = "Locação de veículos Tipo Ônibus";
$lista = ["a", "o", "as", "os", "com", "em", "por", "per", "ante", "contra", "entre", "sem", "após", "de", "para", "sob", "até", "desde", "perante", "sobre"];

foreach(($texto = explode(" ", $texto)) as $i => $s) {
    if (in_array(strtolower($s), $lista)) {
        unset($texto[$i]);
    }
}

echo implode(', ', array_filter($texto));
```

Resultado:

> Locação, veículos, Tipo, Ônibus

*Talvez possa usar algum tipo de `preg_replace` ou afins, mas dá no mesmo.*

---

Se quiser "ocultar palavras curtas", baseado justamente em seu comprimento, poderia usar um simples:

```
echo preg_replace("/(^|\s)[a-z]{1,3}\s/", " ", "Locação de veículos Tipo Ônibus");
```

Isso, assumindo que "curto" seria até 3 caracteres (definido no `{1,3}`). Isso pode funcionar, mas existem efeitos colaterais, já que existem várias palavras com 3 caracteres (ego, réu, ter, vir, vim, dor, luz, voo, voz...) e existem preposições com mais de 3 caracteres (como o "para").

Comment: Inicialmente tinha pensado ocultar todas as palavras curtas, mas como você mesmo disse, haveria efeitos colaterais, pois há palavras curtas e siglas importantes que passariam batido. Meu problema era somente as preposições. Me ajudou bastante, obrigado!  :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$titulo   = 'Locacao de onibus';
$palavras = explode(' ', $titulo);

$ocultar = ['de', 'para', 'com'];

$resultado = array_diff($palavras, $ocultar);
$resultado = implode(' ', $resultado);
?>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado! :)

Comment: E se a string contiver uma outra palavra a ser removida que não está dentro desse array $ocultar? E se a palavra estiver com letra maiúscula? Não seria melhor criar um filtro utilizando o tamanho da palavra como critério, ao invés de comprar a palavra inteira?

Comment: pega $titulo e converte para minúsculo antes mb_strtolower()

Comment: E se a palavra contiver acento? E se a palavra estiver seguida de uma vírgula? E se ela não existir no array? Você sugere incluir todas as palavras da língua portuguesa em $ocultar? Novamente, acho que essa solução poderia ser repensada.

Comment: @user140828, nenhuma solução será perfeita. Para resolver todas essas questões teria que ser algo extremamente elaborado, como por exemplo o NLTK (para Python) ou Prose (para Golang), que são ferramentas para tratamento de texto-humano. Acredito que nenhuma resposta aqui irá tentar "reescrever" estas bibliotecas, indicar o uso dessas ferramentas para um escopo tão limitado não me parece razoável, assim com nem sei a eficiência de tais ferramentas para esse proposito. De todas as formas, você pode adicionar uma nova resposta também.